# In Google sheets, can a QUERY statement determine the oldest date in a column, add 6 months to it , then display that range?

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I am having to query the entire set, jot down the oldest date, and then add a GTE (>=) and a LTE (<=) back into the query statement to limit the results to 6 months, like this:

=QUERY(RawData!A1:D, "SELECT * WHERE A = 'N502SY' and C >= date '2020-03-20' and C <= date '2020-09-20' ORDER BY C ASC")

Ideally, the query statement would determine ON ITS OWN what the oldest date is and then display all rows found with that date PLUS all rows that have a date within a 6-month period (from the oldest date).

Have done a ton of google searching to find an answer but have come to the conclusion that QUERY statements may not be as robust as I am hoping for. Here is the URL (kindly do not change the raw date):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17n3PYBrhlbD1RIgToohS3a1QbN5qhrQnREcMAnZdcbY/edit#gid=626607315

Comment: Your sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely. Make sure you show your desired results in the sample spreadsheet as well.

Answer (score 1):

your shared sheet has restricted access. so here's a working formula based on rough sample data.

`=QUERY(A:D, "SELECT * WHERE A = 'N502SY' and C >= date '"&text(EDATE(MAX(C:C),-6),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  and C <= date '"&text(MAX(C:C),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  ORDER BY C ASC")`

-

[image]

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to open up the sheet. I'll fix that. I'm showing a #NUM error connected to the EDATE, but I'm definitely getting close!

Comment: Try this: =QUERY(RawData!A:D, "SELECT * WHERE A = 'N502SY' and C >= date '"&text(EDATE(MAX(RawData!C:C),-6),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ORDER BY C ASC")

Answer (score 0):

You can try with FILTER and SORT too:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A1:D,A:A="N502SY",C:C>=EDATE(MAX(C:C),-6)),3,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I'm getting a #N/A error, something about a mismatched range. I'll continue hacking away :)